# Constructor parameter validation code doesn't compile

Tags: class, validation, constructor, f#, arguments

I'm trying to write a simple abstract class in F# with some basic parameter validation:

```ml
[<AbstractClass>]
type Record(recordType: int16) =
    let recordType: int16 = recordType

    do
        if recordType < 0s then
            invalidArg (nameof recordType)
```

However, I'm getting an error on the last line: 'this if expression is missing an else branch.' I tried adding an else branch that just evaluates to null, but then the type system doesn't agree with my code. Am I doing something wrong? Should I be validating my arguments using some other method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `invalidArg` requires a parameter name (which you've passed as `nameof recordType` as well as an error message, which you left off, and your if branch returns a function (`string -> 'a` as the return type is unknown/unreachable since the exception is thrown).

If you look at the [docs for invalidArg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/exception-handling/the-invalidarg-function), you see this: `invalidArg parameter-name error-message-string`. Your code is effectively like this:

```
// This is a function: string -> 'a (as it raises an exception, the return type is unknown)
let partialInvalidArg = invalidArg (nameof recordType)
if recordType < 0s then
    partialInvalidArg // You're returning a function, not unit, so the compiler complains
```

If you include the error message, the function is actually called in the branch, and this will compile fine:

```
[<AbstractClass>]
type Record(recordType: int16) =
    let recordType: int16 = recordType

    do
        if recordType < 0s then
            invalidArg (nameof recordType) "The recordType must be greater or equal to zero"
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize it required 2 args. I'd totally discounted currying; unfortunately it tends to make error messages more confusing sometimes.